# rename files and dirs under linux

Tags: find

why the following command " find  /  -name '*node1*'  -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's/node1/node_STAR/' " not replace the node1 under /var/tmp directory?

my target is to scan linux sys and rename directories and files

example from my linux machine

```
pwd
/var/tmp/Change_host_dir
find  /  -name '*node1*'  -print0 | xargs -0
/var/tmp/Change_host_dir/node1
find  /  -name '*node1*'  -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's/node1/node_STAR/'
ls
node1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard linux `rename` command man page says:

> rename will rename the specified files by replacing the first occurrence of *from* in their name by *to*.

so it's just for simple file renames.  This is the standard rename from util-linux, available on all linux systems I am aware of.

I think you are probably trying to use Larry Wall's [example perl rename script](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch09_10.htm).  If that's what you really want, create this file in your path:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
# rename script examples from lwall:
#       rename 's/\.orig$//' *.orig
#       rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/ unless /^Make/' *
#       rename '$_ .= ".bad"' *.f
#       rename 'print "$_: "; s/foo/bar/ if <stdin> =~ /^y/i' *

$op = shift;
for (@ARGV) {
    $was = $_;
    eval $op;
    die $@ if $@;
    rename($was,$_) unless $was eq $_;
}
```

make it executable with `chmod 755 rename`, and call it instead of the system rename.  I tested it with your example and it works.

Comment: hi I save your perl script as rename.pl and I run find  /  -name '*node1*'  -print0 | xargs -0  rename.pl 's/node1/node_STAR/' but I still have the node1 in place to get node_STAR ?

Comment: call rename.pl like this instead: `rename 'print "changing $_\n"; s/node1/node_STAR/'`

Comment: I perfrom mv rename.pl rename and run find  /  -name '*node1*'  -print0 | xargs -0 rename 'print "changing $_\n"; s/node1/node_STAR/'  but still not work why?

Comment: if you run it the second way with `changing $_` you should see the output `changing node1` from rename.  Do you see that?

Comment: OK I fix that need to call it rename.pl with full path then its works

Comment: but there is problem if I have for example node11 then its also replace to node1_START how to replace only if I have full match only

Comment: rename 's/^node1$/node_STAR/' will change *only* node1 filenames.

Comment: good Job its works

Answer (score 1):

try with

> find / -name *node1* -exec rename
>   blahblah {} \;

Comment: stiil not works I run your command but node1 not renamed -(:

Comment: of course ....  try to replace rename blahblah with mv node1 node_START

Comment: I get error mv: target `/var/tmp/Change_host_dir/node1' is not a directory

Comment: @Fotis  my target is to rename dirs or files recursive under /

Comment: I don't know ... but certainly it's working for me :> maybe you could try mv node1 node_Star/ {Play with the '/' }

Comment: @Fotis why not be rename mv isnt good because I need to rename files or dirs recursive under /